# Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `o' or `of'

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, nodes

I am getting a unhelpful error while trying to place a node above another node using the `below=` syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[] (node1) at (0, 0) {Node 1};
  \node[
    below = 5pt of node1
  ] (node2) {Node 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator 'o' or 'of' (in '5pt of node1').
```

How can I place nodes in relation to other nodes without getting an error message?

Comment: I recently had the same, even with a documented example. I used ktikz. I then copied it to a normal document and it word. I then made sure that the programs in ktikz had the full path and restarted ktikz. The problem seems to be gone.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `<placement>=<distance> of <node>.<anchor>` syntax only works with the advanced `positioning` library. The parts

- `distance` and
- `of <node>.<anchor>` are both optional as

  - `.<anchor>` is too.

Depending of `<placement>` the `anchor` key of the to-be-placed node is  internally set according to the following table. The third column shows the default `<anchor>` if the `.<anchor>` part is omitted. (The sans-`positioning` `<placement>` key is just a better-to-comprehend version of the `anchor` key.)

```
 <placement>    anchor        .<anchor>
——————————————————————————————————————————
 above          south         .south
 left           east          .west
 below          north         .south
 right          west          .east
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
 base left      base east     .base west
 base right     base west     .base east
 mid left       mid east      .mid west
 mid right      mid west      .mid east
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
 above left     south west    .north east
 above right    south east    .north west
 below left     north west    .south east
 below right    north east    .south west
```

If no `<distance>` is given, the value of `node distance` is taken.

Note that for the four bottom ones the `<distance>` part can consist of `<vertical distance> and <horizontal distance>`. (The same is true for the `node distance` key that is enhanced by the `positioning` library also.)

The `on grid` option sets both anchors (the one of the to-be-placed node as well as the referenced `.<anchor>`) to `.center` so that the nodes are placed in a grid.

*The topics covered by the last two paragraphs are further explained in the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) in section 16.5.3 “Advanced Placement Options”, pp. 185ff.*

### Example (with `positioning` library)

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes=draw]
  \node (node1) at (0, 0) {Node 1};
  \node[below=5pt of node1] (node2) {Node 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Example (without `positioning` library)

Without the `positioning` library this can be achieved by combining

- the old `<placement>=<distance>` and
- the `at=<node>.<opposite anchor>` key,

where `<opposite anchor>` is the corresponding `.<anchor>` of the table above.

The correct `anchor` part is set without the `positioning` library, too.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes=draw]
  \node (node1) at (0, 0) {Node 1};
  \node[below=5pt,at=(node1.south)] (node2) {Node 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Mandatory: [Difference between `right of=` and `right=of` in PGF/TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386)

Answer (score 23):

The positioning library is missing:

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
```