# Tikz: Text along top and bottom of arrow path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, text-decorations, decorations

How can I add text to both the top and bottom of a path?  My commutative diagram below is 90% complete.  I would, however, like `text={${gKer({\varphi}){\mapsto}{\varphi(G)}}$}` following the path below the arrow and `\cong` following the path above the same arrow.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (A) {$G$};
\node (B) [right of=A] {$G'$};
\node (C) [below of=A] {$G/Ker(\varphi)$};

\draw[->>] (A) --(B) node[above,midway] {$\varphi$};
\draw[->,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={${\pi}{\;}$}}}] (A) to node[swap] {} (C);
\draw[->,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align = center,text={${gKer({\varphi}){\mapsto}{\varphi(G)}}$}}}] (C) to node[swap] {} (B);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use the `text along path` decoration on a straight path? It would be simpler to do `\path (a) -- node[below] {stuff} node[above] {other stuff} (b) ;`. Also, take a look at the `tikz-cd` package. By the way, the syntax `<direction> of=<node>` is deprecated (and you do not use the `positioning` library that way): [\[1\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386), [\[2\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94396/16595)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest you tu use the [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) package for your commutative diagrams; also, since the problematic label is not really the name of a map, but rather its action, I would also suggest you to describe the map outside the diagram (otherwise, the diagram might result too crowded):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
G\arrow[twoheadrightarrow]{r}{\varphi}\arrow{d}{\pi} & G' \\
G/\Ker(\varphi)\arrow[sloped,swap]{ur}[near start]{\tau}[swap]{\cong}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
where $\tau:G/\Ker(\varphi)\rightarrow G'$ is defined by $g\Ker({\varphi}){\mapsto}{\varphi(G)}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can draw the diagram with the originally requested labels, perhaps increasing the distance between nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=60pt,column sep=huge]
G\arrow[twoheadrightarrow]{r}{\varphi}\arrow{d}{\pi} & G' \\
G/\Ker(\varphi)\arrow[sloped,swap]{ur}[pos=0.15]{g\Ker({\varphi}){\mapsto}{\varphi(G)}}[swap]{\cong}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice the use of

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}
```

(requires the `amsmath` package) to produce the correct shape for the `Ker` operator; (I initially overlooked this, but  **Ethan Bolker** signaled it out in a comment).

Comment: This is great, how can I lengthen the arrows?

Comment: @beethree you can use `row sep` and/or `column sep`,for example: `\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge,column sep=huge]...\end{tikzcd}` (refer to the package documentation for other valid values) or even `\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=90pt,column sep=200pt]...\end{tikzcd}`

Comment: Thank you, your code above worked great. `\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3.5 cm,column sep=3.5cm]` gave me enough room.

Comment: @beethree You're welcome. I added another example with the initial labels.

Comment: You might want `\text{Ker}` to keep `Ker` from being a sequence of three italicized variables. Or use `\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}` .

Comment: @EthanBolker yes; I'll edit my answer to incorporate your suggestion, Thanks.