# How to decrease the counter in tikz foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0.5cm, auto]
\node (0) {Block 0};
\node (1) [below= of 0.south] {Block 1};
\node (2) [below= of 1.south] {Block 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It prints this:

[image]

I tried to do the same with pgf loop, but don't know how to decrease the counter:

```
\foreach \x in {0,...,2}
{
  \ifnum\x=0\relax
      \node (\x) {Block \x};
  \else
      %\prev=\x - 1 <- ???
      \node (\x) [below= of \prev.south] {Block \x};
  \fi
}
```

Comment: The `.south` is not needed, see [Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94386)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Plz, mention, that I included `positioning` library at the top snippet. So, it's ok.

Comment: As the linked question shows, the `positioning` library actually makes `=of` possible. What I meant was, that `below` implicitly sets the `.south` anchor of the “`of`” node. It doesn’t hurt either.

Comment: You might prefer naming nodes with some other pattern because right now it's hanging in the balance waiting TikZ to confuse it with a regular number :)

Comment: In this simple case we can also use `\foreach \x [remember=\x as \eval] in …` and don't need to calculate anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use math :)

```
\foreach \x in {0,...,2}{
  \ifnum\x=0\relax
      \node (\x) {Block \x};
  \else
      \pgfmathparse{int(\x-1)}
      \node (\x) [below= of \pgfmathresult.south] {Block \x};
  \fi
}
```

Comment: [*Must... resist... posting... this... link...*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gENVB6tjq_M) `:)`

Answer (score 5):

Besides using `\pgfmathparse{int(…)}` you can also use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` or:

1. eTeX’s `\numexpr`,
2. `\foreach`’s `evaluate` (again with `int`),
3. `\foreach`’s `remember`,
4. `\foreach`’s `count` starting `from -1` (i.e. first `\x` minus one)
5. (recommended) the `chains` library with `start chain=<chain name> going below`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains}
\tikzset{node distance=.5cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,...,2}{
  \ifnum\x=0\relax
      \node (\x) {Block \x};
  \else
      \node (\x) [below=of \number\numexpr\x-1\relax] {Block \x};
  \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x[evaluate=\x as \eval using int(\x-1)] in {0,...,2}{
  \ifnum\x=0\relax
      \node (\x) {Block \x};
  \else
      \node (\x) [below=of \eval] {Block \x};
  \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x[remember=\x as \eval] in {0,...,2}{
  \ifnum\x=0\relax
      \node (\x) {Block \x};
  \else
      \node (\x) [below=of \eval] {Block \x};
  \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x[count=\eval from -1] in {0,...,2}{
  \ifnum\x=0\relax
      \node (\x) {Block \x};
  \else
      \node (\x) [below=of \eval] {Block \x};
  \fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going below]
\foreach \x in {0,...,2}
  \node[on chain] (\x) {Block \x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output (all solutions)

[image]