# How to make a zero-size node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I make a node with zero size and node distance, such that a node that is positioned to the right of it lies on the same spot?

My solution to the first node in a node-drawing loop was to start with an invisible node, but I can't make it smaller. I'd be happy with a better solution, too.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{intcalc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \tikzstyle{frame} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,
        text width=2em, text centered, minimum height=2em, node distance=1.5cm]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (f0) {}; % This one is too big
        \foreach \framenum in {1,...,7}{
            \def\frameangle{\intcalcMul{ \intcalcDec{\intcalcMod{\framenum}{3}} }{8}} % 0, 8, -8, ...
            \def\lastframenum{\intcalcDec{\framenum}}
            \node [frame, right of=f\lastframenum] (f\framenum)
                {$f_\framenum$ $\frameangle^\circ$};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Edit: Here is the result with `\coordinate (f0) {}`:

[image]

Comment: Use `\coordinate` instead of `\node`

Comment: Thanks! There still seems to be some space left, but I don't think it will be noticeable. Do you know what's causing it?

Comment: The line break after the end of the `\tikzstyle` adds a space character, add a `%` at the end of that line. I.e. `... node distance=1.5cm]%`. Edit: forgot a reference: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453

Comment: By the way, the height of the boxes are not identical, as you've probably noticed. Increasing the `minimum height` to `2.7em` fixes that.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. While we're at it, here's another reference: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372) — Besides that, `\tikzset` and `\tikzstyle` should go in the preamble (where they don't create spaces), when the assignments aren't local to one TikZ picture, in this case they should be used in the optional argument of the TikZ picture.

Comment: @Jake That's a nice suggestion. Is it possible to use a label for a coordinate? (something simple like `node[label=below:hi]` )

Comment: @Jake Sorry. I found the solution: just use `coorditnate[label=below:hi]`. For some reason, `coordinate (someName)[label=below:hi]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There were/are certain problems in your code:

The first one, as pointed out by Jake, was that you used a node where you should use a coordinate (which is a shape-less node, namely only a point).

Then, as pointed out by TorbjørnT., you inserted a spurious space at the end of `\tikzstyle` assignment. The `\tikzstyle` macro is long deprecated and should be replaced with the more flexible `\tikzset`. This wouldn't have helped with the space, though. I advice you to move any global assignments in the preamble where you don't have to take care of spaces. Is this style only used in this TikZ picture in your document, move its declaration to the optional argument of `\begin{tikzpicture}` (or use a `\tikzset` inside the environment where it normally doesn’t create a space either):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[frame/.style={…, …}]
```

Then we have the `right of` syntax which is also deprecated. Use the `positioning` library and the `right=of <lastnode>` syntax.

You don’t even need this auxiliary code if you check inside the `\foreach` loop whether you have the first node or not:

```
\ifnum\framenum=1
    \node[frame] (f\framenum) {…};
\else
    \node[frame, right=of f\lastframenum] (f\framenum) {…};
\fi
```

There is also no need for the `\intCalcDec` macro, you have used the `remember` option of the `\foreach` loop:

```
\foreach \framenum[remember=\framenum as \lastframenum] in {1,...,7}{
```

or you could just do the calculation with eTeX’s `\numexpr`:

```
\node [frame, right=of f\number\numexpr\framenum-1\relax] (f\framenum) {…};
```

Take a look at reference 5 for a small overview on this topic.

While the `intcalc` package is surely a great package; PGF has a lot of mathematical functions built-in, which we can use in the `evaluate` option of the `\foreach` loop:

```
\foreach \frameNum[
    evaluate=\frameNum as \frameAngle using {int(8*(mod(\frameNum,3)-1))}
] in {1,...,7}
```

---

But why go through all that trouble when the TikZ’ `chains` library does all the work for us when we `start`a `chain` at the overlaying `scope` level (the `tikzpicture` implies a scope), and then set every node `on` this `chain`.

Without the `frame` style definition this becomes nearly a one-liner:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
    \foreach \frameNum[
        evaluate=\frameNum as \frameAngle using {int(8*(mod(\frameNum,3)-1))}
    ] in {1,...,7}
        \node [frame, on chain] (f\frameNum){$f_\frameNum$ $\frameAngle^\circ$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

I also switched to the `minimum size` option (which sets `minimum height` and `minimum width`, and inserted an manual linebreak.

TorbjørnT. also detected that the height of the nodes is not always the same, and in fact the minus sign seems to add a depth to the last line. We can overwrite this by setting `text depth` to `0pt` which will only work for the last line. For other cases, you can use the `\smash` macro and/or (provided by the `amsmath` package) the `b` option: `$\smash[b]{\frameAngle^\circ}$`.

#### References

1. [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453)
2. [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372)
3. [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386)
4. [Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `o' or `of'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94386/16595) (it’s an overview of the `positioning` library)
5. [How to decrease the counter in tikz foreach loop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110376/16595)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning}
\tikzset{
    frame/.style={
        rectangle,
        draw,
        fill=blue!20,
        align=center,
        minimum size=2\baselineskip,
        node distance=0.5cm
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain]
    \foreach \frameNum[
        evaluate=\frameNum as \frameAngle using {int(8*(mod(\frameNum,3)-1))}
    ] in {1,...,7}
        \node [frame, text depth=+0pt, on chain] (f\frameNum){$f_\frameNum$\\$\frameAngle^\circ$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Nicely composed answer!

Comment: Thank you very much! I learnt a lot from this unexpected code review. I'll try to sneak unnecessary code into my future questions, too.