# How to place a symbol under an arrow in Latex when using tikz package

Tags: symbols, tikz-pgf

I'm using the `tikz` package in LaTeX to construct a feedback loop for a control system as a part of a paper on control systems. The problem I'm running into is that I would like to place symbols under the arrows between the blocks in addition to the symbols which are currently above the arrows. For example I would like to place a symbol for `$phi$` below the arrow, under the `$tau$` symbol. I have no idea how to achieve this since I'm fairly new to LaTeX and `tikz`. Any help would be appreciated.

I've embedded all of my code below, as well as a snapshot of how the feedbackloop currently looks with the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=15pt]{standalone}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}


\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=gray!3, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=gray!3, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
 \node [input, name=input] {};
 \node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
 \node [block, right of=sum] (controller) {Regulator};
 \node [block, right of=controller, node distance=3cm] (motor) {G$_{motor}$};
 \node [block, right of=motor, pin={[pinstyle]above:Störningar},
        node distance=3cm] (system) {Dynamik$_{\varphi}$};

 \draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=u] {$u$} (motor);
 \node [output, right of=system] (output) {};
 \node [block, below of=motor] (msystem) {Mätsystem};

 \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$\varphi_{ref}$} (sum);
 \draw [->] (sum) -- node {$e$} (controller);
 \draw [->] (motor) -- node {$\tau$} (system);
 \draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$\varphi$}(output);
 \draw [->] (y) |- (msystem);
 \draw [->] (msystem) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$}  node [near end] {$\varphi_m$} (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Replace `\draw [->] (y) |- (msystem);` with `\draw [->] (y) |-  node[pos=0.95] {$\varphi$} (msystem);`.

Comment: Or `\node [below] at (tau |- msystem) {$\varphi$};` where `tau` is the name of the `$\tau$` node. — Also, take a look at [Should `\tikzset` or `\tikzstyle` be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372), [Difference between `right of=` and `right=of` in PGF/TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386) and [Package PGF Math Error: ``Unknown operator `o' or `of'``](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94386/94396#94396)

Answer (score 5):

You can use multiple `label` keys in the options for a node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mynode/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=2cm}]
\node[mynode,label=left:$a$,label=right:$b$,label=60:$c$,label=220:$d$] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In your case, you need an additional precaution since you declared `auto` globally, so you need to use `auto=false` for the node that will have multiple labels:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows}

\tikzset{
block/.style = {draw, fill=gray!3, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=6em},
sum/.style = {draw, fill=gray!3, circle, node distance=1cm},
input/.style = {coordinate},
output/.style = {coordinate},
pinstyle/.style={pin edge={to-,thin,black}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,>=latex']
 \node [input, name=input] {};
 \node [sum, right = of input] (sum) {};
 \node [block, right = of sum] (controller) {Regulator};
 \node [block, right = of controller, node distance=3cm] (motor) {G$_{motor}$};
 \node [block, right  = of motor, pin={[pinstyle]above:Störningar},
        node distance=3cm] (system) {Dynamik$_{\varphi}$};

 \draw [->] (controller) -- node[name=u,auto] {$u$} (motor);
 \node [output, right=of system] (output) {};
 \node [block, below  = of motor] (msystem) {Mätsystem};
 \draw [draw,->] (input) -- node[auto] {$\varphi_{ref}$} (sum);
 \draw [->] (sum) -- node[auto] {$e$} (controller);
 \draw [->] (motor) -- node[auto=false,label=below:$\varphi$,label=above:$\tau$] {}  (system);
 \draw [->] (system) -- node [auto,name=y] {$\varphi$}(output);
 \draw [->] (y) |- (msystem);
 \draw [->] (msystem) -| node[auto,pos=0.99] {$-$}  node [auto,near end] {$\varphi_m$} (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice also that I replaced the old `\tikzstyle` for the newer `\tikzset` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like

```
\draw [->] (motor) edge node[above] {$\tau$} node[below] {$\phi$} (system);
```

should do this

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Answer (score 0):

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, calc}
\tikzset{%
port/.style     = {inner sep=0pt, font=\tiny},
sum/.style n args = {4}{draw, circle, node distance = 2cm, minimum size=.6cm, alias=sum,
    append after command={
        (sum.45) -- (sum.225)
        (sum.135) -- (sum.315)
        node at (sum.north) [port, below=1pt] {\textbf{#1}}
        node at (sum.west) [port, right=1pt] {\textbf{#2}}
        node at (sum.south) [port, above=1pt] {\textbf{#3}}
        node at (sum.east) [port, left=1pt] {\textbf{#4}}
    },
},
}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw node at (0, 0) [sum={}{+}{–}{}] (sum1) {}
    node [tf, right = of sum1] (tf1) {$G_C(s)$}
    node [tf, right = of tf1] (tf2) {$G_P(s)$}
    node at ($(tf2) + (1,0)$) [branch] (circ1) {};
    \draw[-Latex] (-1.5, 0) -- node [label = {[above, pos = .4]:$R(s)$}] () {} (sum1.west);
    \draw[-Latex] (tf1.east) -- (tf2.west);
    \draw[-Latex] (tf2.east) -- node [label = {[above, pos = .75]:$Y(s)$}] () {} ($(circ1)+(1,0)$);
    \draw[-Latex] (sum1.east) -- (tf1.west);
    \draw[-Latex] (circ1) -- ($(circ1) - (0, 1)$) -| (sum1.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image: Sample control system.]

This is someone else's code, I just modified it a little bit. I couldn't find the original post. So kudos to him/her, whoever posted this code's original form.

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- make your code snippet compilable for a fast proof ...