# Replicate a Fancy Poster: TikZ relative position of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, unicode-math

I'm looking into replicating (or approaching) the following poster/cheatsheet produced by the International Baccalaureate Organization:

[image]

In positioning the nodes/boxes relative to each other, I have found that I had to tweak `node distance=` on a case by case basis: Is there a way to set so that the vertical and horizontal distances are the same irrespective of the size of the boxes?

If anyone knows how to set up a font that more closely resembles the original, I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions. I haven't looked into replicating the style of the figures yet, that's for another day!

Here's my attempt at positioning boxes:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TeX spellcheck = fr
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[landscape,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% font stuff
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Bradley Hand}
\setmathfont{GFS Neohellenic Math}

% tikz libraries
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

% Define box styles
% Define box styles
\tikzset{boxstyle/.style={draw=Gold, minimum height=1ex, minimum width=5em},
         fluffybox/.style={boxstyle, fill=white, very thick,
             decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt,amplitude=1pt}},
         doublebox/.style = {boxstyle, fill=Lavender!50, thick, double},
         line/.style = {very thick, draw=Gold},
         pointer/.style = {very thick, draw=Gold, -latex'}
}    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % title
  \node [doublebox] (A) {Interesting Title};
  % node A
  \node [fluffybox, below of=A] (B) {%
    $ \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}
       \int_0^{2 \muppi} \frac{t^2}{2} \mathop{\symup{d}t} \leq
       \sum_{i=1}^N  \frac{\muppi i}{\sqrt 2} \approx \increment \symbfup{v}t
    $
  };
  % node B
  \node [fluffybox, node distance=5cm, right of=B] (C) {%
    $ \frac{\sin \theta}{\Theta} =
      \frac{\sin \varphi}{\Phi} = 
      \frac{\sin \gamma}{\Gamma} 
    $
  };
  % edge
  \path [line] (B) -- (C);
  % node C
  \node [fluffybox, node distance=2cm, below of=B] (D) {%
    $ x^n+y^n = z^n $
  };
  % pointer
  \path [pointer] (B) -- (D);
  % title
  \node [doublebox, below of=C] (E) {Lettres Intéressantes: ç, ï, ê, œ};
  % image
  \node [fluffybox, node distance=2cm, below of=E] (F) {%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth,height=0.3\textheight,keepaspectratio]%
      {example-image-a.jpg}
  };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm compiling with `XeLaTeX` and plan to write a French version of this, hence the experiment with accents.

**EDIT** If I set the node distances globally, say `\tikzset{node distance = 2cm and 2cm}`, I get the correct distance for some boxes but not for others, e.g.:

[image]

Comment: does this help - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332796/197451.-- also what about using a table to place the figures at equidistant in rows and columns or a matrix

Comment: Also, it is better to use tilzset instead of `tikzstyle` which is deprecated.

`\tikzset{inicio/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=yellow},
           nodo/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black},
}`

Comment: Thanks @jsbibra, I'll update to `\tikset`. So I don't want a table with fixed widths and heights, but instead randomly sized and positioned boxes that have a fixed distance between them. Thanks!

Comment: for fixed distance use the link - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332796/197451

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't produce the expected result. I'm updating the question to explain.

Comment: The font looks like "Barter with Gypsy". https://www.whatfontis.com/FF_Barter-with-a-Gypsy-Bold.font?

Comment: @anis, Oh! great. Would you know how to set it up? I tried `\setmainfont{BarterwithaGypsy}` without success. (what a font name that is)

Comment: Let me make an answer.

Comment: For the drawing part, I still don't understand what you want to achieve vs what you have.

Comment: For the box positioning, I would like to set the distance between one box's edge and the next box's edge to be a fixed distance, say 2cm, and not have to tweak on a case by case basis based on the size of the box, as I am doing in the code above.

Comment: Use this syntax: `[fluffybox, right = of B.east]`. you can even go for `[fluffybox, right = of B.east, anchor=west]`. it basically indicates that exact distance between the east anchor of the node B is `node distance` from the west anchor of the current node.

Comment: @PatrickT Great summary. Would you mind posting the final result ? Much interested :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing, positioning}
\tikzset{
cloudframed/.style={path picture={
\draw[orange!30!yellow, ultra thick, fill=white]
decorate[decoration={bent, amplitude=3pt}]{
decorate[decoration={random steps, segment length=12pt, amplitude=1pt}]{
([shift={(5pt,5pt)}]path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle ([shift={(-5pt,-5pt)}]path picture bounding box.north east)
}};}},
boxstyle/.style={cloudframed, align=left, inner sep=10pt, font=\sc\bf},
conn/.style={orange!30!yellow, ultra thick},
node distance=0.5cm and 0.5cm,
}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background, main, foreground}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[boxstyle] (A) {$Z\sim N(0,1)$};
\node[boxstyle, right=of A] (B) {Z is the number of\\standard deviations\\away from mean};
\node[boxstyle, below=of B, minimum size=4cm] (C) {};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw[conn] (A.center) -- (B.center);
\draw[conn] (B.center) -- (C.center);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Three yellow boxes with a cloud shaped border]

Comment: does the trick thank you so much! I'll have to investigate the font issues separately (sounds like no small feat from what anis said in a comment!)

Comment: Yes - it is alway better to ask several questions (and add links to old ones, if it is needed for context) with smaller self contained questions/tasks.

Answer (score 1):

For the font part:

The font looks like "Barter with a Gypsy". [whatfontis.com](https://whatfontis.com/FF_Barter-with-a-Gypsy-Bold.font?)

Using `xelatex`I  can compile the following:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[]{Barter with a Gypsy}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

The font has to be downloaded and installed first (double click the ttf file and press install).

Edit: there supposedly exists a way to load fonts from a folder but  I could not make it work.

See: [Load fonts that are in a ./fonts directory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12565/load-fonts-that-are-in-a-fonts-directory)

Comment: Thanks @anis! So this prints basic text, but not the accents and math above. Any thoughts?

Comment: Bater with a Gypsy doesn't define accented characters. https://www.dafont.com/barter-with-a-gypsy.font?text=%E9crire. To my knowledge, there are two ways: define a new font that does or manually create a macro that adds an image of the size of a character. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13594/how-to-add-a-custom-symbol-to-latex . Both are terrible. You may want to open a new question for this specific case.

Comment: Thanks @anis for the tip!