# TikZ and tabular/multicol

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've just finished my first TikZ flowchart, and I have a couple of wished to improve it, but I can't seem to search my way to a solution.
I would like do this in 2 colomns, with dashed a line between them. As you can see, theres one node, where the dashed line is intented to be. Is it possible to make a tabular or multicol, in a way where thats possible?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin={30mm,0mm},hmargin={0mm,0mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, shadows, calc}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=gray!20, 
text width=8em, text centered, minimum height=4em, drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners,fill=white!20, node distance=2cm,
minimum height=2em, drop shadow]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm]
\node [block, xshift=12em] (post) {\large Postmoderne};
\node [block, xshift=-12em] (modern) {\large Moderne};
\node [cloud, below of=modern, node distance=7em, fill=red!20] (auto) {Øget             \emph{control}};
\node [cloud, below of=auto] (active) {\emph{Active learning} og positive udviklingsspiral};
\node [cloud, below of=active] (effect) {Mere effektivitet og positive emotioner};
\node [cloud, below of=post, node distance=4em, fill=red!20] (sparring) {Sparringssamarbejde};
\node [cloud, below of=sparring, node distance=3em] (support) {Øget social support};
\node [cloud, below of=support, node distance=11em] (kom) {Bedre kommunikation og gensidig respekt};
\node [cloud, below of=modern, node distance=24em, xshift=12em, fill=green!20] (res) {Resiliens hos medarbejder og organisation};


\path [line] (sparring) -- (support);
\path [line] (auto) -- (active);
\path [line] (active) -- (effect);
\path [line] (support) -- (active);
\path [line] (active) -- (kom);
\path [line] (kom) -- (res);
\path [line] (effect) -- (res);



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Frederik and welcome to the site. I get an error when I compile your code, and I think it's to do with the unicode characters like `Ø` in your file. It might just be my machine. (`ERROR: Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined in inputencoding latin1.`) PS `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` works for me.

Comment: When your nodes are arranged in a roughly "grid-like" way, you can put them in a `matrix`. The `matrix` is the TikZ counterpart to the LaTeX `tabular` or `array`.

Comment: Hi John.
Thanks for the quick answer. I forgot to mention my danish heritage, hence the odd characters.

Comment: Det var så lidt `:-)`. And do feel free to ask for any clarification regarding my answer, if needed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se! The `\tikzstyle` macros are deprecated, see [Should `\tikzset` or `\tikzstyle` be used to define TikZ styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372). The position keys `below of` (and others) are also depcreated, see [Difference between `right of=` and `right=of` in PGF/TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a first attempt.

- I put your nodes into a `matrix`. This is like a LaTeX `tabular` environment, and makes the positioning of nodes in a grid very easy.
- Unfortunately, unless I am mistaken, it is rather hard to draw lines between rows or columns in a TikZ `matrix`. You don't have column specifiers, for instance, like you do for `tabular`, so you can't write `{c|c}` to get two centred columns with a line between.
- What I did was to draw a line from the top-centre point of the matrix to the bottom-centre point. This only looks right if the two columns are roughly the same width.
- **Update.** I use `shorten >=-3cm` to shorten the bottom end of the dashed line by `-3cm`; that is, to lengthen it by `3cm`. You can also write `shorten <=-1 cm` to extend the top end.

### Code

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin={30mm,0mm},hmargin={0mm,0mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows, shadows, calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=gray!20, 
text width=8em, text centered, minimum height=4em, drop shadow]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, rectangle, rounded corners,fill=white!20, node distance=2cm,
minimum height=2em, drop shadow]

\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (m) [column sep=2cm,row sep=2cm] {
  \node [block] (modern) {\large Moderne}; 
& \node [block] (post) {\large Postmoderne}; 
\\
& \node [cloud, fill=red!20] (sparring) {Sparringssamarbejde}; 
\\
  \node [cloud, fill=red!20] (auto) {Øget \emph{control}};
& \node [cloud] (support) {Øget social support}; 
\\
  \node [cloud] (active) {\emph{Active learning} og positive udviklingsspiral};
\\
  \node [cloud] (effect) {Mere effektivitet og positive emotioner};
& \node [cloud] (kom) {Bedre kommunikation og gensidig respekt};
\\
};

\draw[dashed, shorten >=-3cm] (m.north) -- (m.south);

\node [cloud, below of=effect, xshift=12em, fill=green!20] (res) {Resiliens hos medarbejder og organisation};

\path [line] (sparring) -- (support);
\path [line] (auto) -- (active);
\path [line] (active) -- (effect);
\path [line] (support) -- (active);
\path [line] (active) -- (kom);
\path [line] (kom) -- (res);
\path [line] (effect) -- (res);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Wow. That it exactly what I was looking for. Besides the fact that the dashed line cannot go all the way through. But maybe thats just the way? Are you aware of any other complete different way to compose the flowchart, so that it is possible?

Comment: I extended the dashed line downwards by 3cm -- see my updated answer. Regarding the overall composition of the flowchart: this is the right way to do it when your nodes are roughly in a grid like this. If there is not such an obvious grid structure, then the `matrix` may start to lose its appeal.

Comment: Extending with 'shorten' seems a bit weird? But thanks anyway. I think can go from here by searching for bg-colouring, arrowsize etc. One thing, though; How do you control which side the dashed line goes of the green box? Mines in front, but if i use 'your' code, it goes behind. :S

Comment: PS. Good to see some foreigners digging into danish. ;)

Comment: Tak `:-)`. TikZ objects are drawn in the order they appear in your code. So to adjust the "z order" just swap the lines in the code.

Comment: Be careful with shortening with negative amount. The bounding box will not get updated, so the line may extend in the following text. The “z order” can be changed with PGF layers or—very simple—with the `backgrounds` library. With the `positioning` library ([\[1\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94386), [\[2\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386)) it is possible to do, say `\node [cloud, below=1cm of m, fill=green!20] (res) {Resiliens hos medarbejder og organisation}; \begin{scope}[on background layer]\draw[dashed] (m.north) -- ([yshift=-1cm]res.south);\end{scope}`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks. Is `\begin{scope}[on foo layer]...\end{scope}` the same as `\begin{pgfonlayer}{foo}...\end{pgfonlayer}`?

Comment: @JohnWickerson Yes and No. `[on background layer]` does indeed use the `pgfonlayer` environment but the `backgrounds` library also declares the `background` layer itself and sets the right order `background, main`. Though, it wouldn’t be that hard to change `\pgfdeclarelayer` so that it creates the right style. Just adding `\tikzset{on #1 layer/.style={execute at begin scope={\pgfonlayer{#1}},execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayer}}}` should do.