# Automatically setting one node after the other in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've changed a timeline of mine to look like the one asked in this question: [timeline and tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61237/timeline-and-tikz)

Everything went smoothly but I have a problem. I don't know how to automatically set the nodes' position.

Basically their positions should "fixed", starting from (3,0) and then one after the other with a fixed distance between them (regardless if they are one-line or not). After that I'd be making the lines. How can I tell Tikz to automatically get the coordinates of each text node without setting it manually? (This would mean removing the second argument for the command `\evento`.)

I expect the final result to look like the one in the question or like Tom Bombadil's answer but using my code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse,expl3}

\usetikzlibrary{fit, arrows,backgrounds,patterns,shapes,shapes.multipart,positioning,calc,decorations.markings}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\pagestyle{empty}

\tikzset{
    opera/.style={draw, rectangle, align=center, text width=6cm, fill=white, font=\scriptsize},
    typnode/.style={anchor=north west, text width=12cm, inner sep=0mm},
    data/.style={draw=gray, rectangle, fill=white, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=0.5mm},
    datum/.style={font=\scriptsize, rotate=90, inner sep=1mm},
}

\newcommand*{\evento}[3]{
        \coordinate (A) at (0,{(#1-1600)/10});
        \coordinate (B) at (3,{#2});%
        \coordinate[right=5mm of A] (Z);
        \coordinate[left=1cm of B] (Y);
        \draw (A) -- (Z);
        \draw[-|] (Y) -- (B) node[data, pos=0.55] {#1};
        \draw (Z) -- (Y);
        \node[right=3mm of B, typnode] (D) {#3};
}

\begin{document}
        \footnotesize   
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=-7mm]
            \centering
       %draw horizontal line   
       \draw[|->, -latex, draw] (0,0) -- (0,39);
       \draw[-, dashed] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0);
       \draw[|->, -latex, draw] (34,0) -- (34,39);
       \draw[-, dashed] (34,-0.5) -- (34,39);

       %draw years
        \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \xear using int(1600+\y*10)] in {0,1,...,38}{ 
            \draw (0,\y) node[left=2pt,anchor=east,xshift=0,font=\scriptsize] {$\xear$}; 
            \draw (-0.1,\y) -- (0.1,\y);
            }

        \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \xear using int(1600+\y*10)] in {0,1,...,37}{ 
            \draw (0,\y) node[left=2pt,anchor=east,xshift=0,font=\scriptsize] {}; 
            \draw (0,\y+.5) -- (0.1,\y+.5);
            }

        \evento{1603}{0}{King James VI of Scotland ascends to the English throne, becoming James I of England and uniting the crowns - but not the parliaments - of the two kingdoms};
        \evento{1605}{2}{\textbf{5 November} - Gunpowder Plot: A plot in which Guy Fawkes and other Catholic associates conspired to blow up King James VI and I and the Parliament of England was uncovered.};
        \evento{1618}{3}{Walter Raleigh was executed.};
        \evento{1639}{5}{Bishops' Wars: A war with Scotland began which would last until 1640.};
        \evento{1640}{6}{Long Parliament: The Parliament was convened.};
        \evento{1642}{7}{English Civil War: The war began (see timeline of the English Civil War).};
        \evento{1649}{8}{January Trial and execution of Charles I\\Interregnum began with the First Commonwealth};
        \evento{1653}{9}{The Protectorate began under the Lord Protector Oliver Cromwell};
        \evento{1659}{10}{Second Commonwealth a period of great political instability};
        \evento{1660}{11}{Restoration of the monarchy};
        \evento{1666}{12}{\textbf{2 September} - Great Fire of London: A fire began in London.\\\textbf{6 September} - Great Fire of London: The fire ended.};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would use chains here. The `west below` key helps to align the nodes correctly. Its definition is taken from my [`positioning-plus` library](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypositioning-plus.code.tex).

I haven’t followed your `\evento` macro bit for bit but included the lines in the loop. I have removed the `fill=white` from the `data` style as it is not placed on top of a line anymore.

The vertical distances between the `typnode`s is specified via the `node distance` option and is taken between the `south west` of the previous node and the `north west` anchor (“`west below`”) of the new node.

The label (`data`) with the year is placed `base left` of the `typnode` so that they share the same baseline.

One could also make a function out of `{(\Year-1600)/10}` so that you can easily change the *y* axis. There could be very different implementation on how to get the coordinate on the line.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{west below/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{north west}{0}{-1}{south west}{1}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  typnode/.style={anchor=north west, text width=12cm, inner sep=0mm},
  data/.style={draw=gray, rectangle, font=\scriptsize, inner sep=0.5mm},
}
\begin{document}\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=-7mm]
%draw horizontal line
\foreach \xValue in {0,34}
  \path (\xValue,0) edge[-latex] ++(0,39)
                    edge[dashed] ++ (down:1);

%%draw years
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \xear using int(1600+\y*10)] in {0,1,...,38}{ 
  \node[left=2pt,anchor=east,xshift=0,font=\scriptsize] at (0,\y) {$\xear$}; 
  \draw (-0.1,\y) -- (0.1,\y); \draw (0,\y+.5) -- (0.1,\y+.5);
}

\begin{scope}[start chain=ch1 going west below, node distance=+1em]
\foreach \Year/\Text in {%
    1603/{King James VI of Scotland ascends to the English throne, becoming James I of England and uniting the crowns - but not the parliaments - of the two kingdoms},
    1605/{\textbf{5 November} - Gunpowder Plot: A plot in which Guy Fawkes and other Catholic associates conspired to blow up King James VI and I and the Parliament of England was uncovered.},
    1618/{Walter Raleigh was executed.},
    1639/{Bishops' Wars: A war with Scotland began which would last until 1640.},
    1640/{Long Parliament: The Parliament was convened.},
    1642/{English Civil War: The war began (see timeline of the English Civil War).},
    1649/{January Trial and execution of Charles I\\Interregnum began with the First Commonwealth},
    1653/{The Protectorate began under the Lord Protector Oliver Cromwell},
    1659/{Second Commonwealth a period of great political instability},
    1660/{Restoration of the monarchy},
    1666/{\textbf{2 September} - Great Fire of London: A fire began in London.\\\textbf{6 September} - Great Fire of London: The fire ended.}}{
  \node[typnode, at=(right:5cm), on chain=ch1, alias=Text] {\Text};
  \node[data,    base left=+2em of Text, alias=Year] {\Year};
  \draw[-|] (Year.east) -- ++(right:3mm);
  \draw     (Year.west) -- ++(left:3mm)
                        -- ([shift=(right:3mm)] 0,{(\Year-1600)/10})
                        --                     (0,{(\Year-1600)/10});
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I thought I had accepted but I didn't. A side question (if it's easy): is it possible to assign names to the single nodes, either manually (custom names) or automatically (e.g. increasing labels)?

Comment: The main nodes (with the `\Text`) or the ones with the year in it? The main nodes are on the chain and are automatically named `ch1-1`, `ch1-2`, and so on (`ch1` is the name of the chain as defined with the `start chain` key). The first and the last node are also named `ch1-begin` and `ch1-end` respectively.

Comment: Yes those, thanks! I didn't know they were named automatically. :)

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother again, but I was wondering, mind to explain the syntax of `\tikzset{west below/.code=\tikz@lib@place@handle@{#1}{north west}{0}{-1}{south west}{1}}` What do those numbers stand for? Thanks!

Comment: @Alenanno Take a look at the examples from the [`positioning`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarypositioning.code.tex) library and my linked `positioning-plus` library for examples. The macro `\tikz@lib@place@handle@` checks `#1` for `of` and then executes certain macros and sets the new node’s `north west` below (`-1 * <node distance>`) of the referenced node’s `south west` anchor (unless one is given). The `0` is the shifting in *x* direction and the `1` is a factor for `node distance` does only contain one value.

Comment: @Alenanno Take a look at these answers of mine: [\[1\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94396) and [\[2\]](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135386). Feel free to ask a follow-up question if I should go more into detail. The `west below` is basically a `below` key that left-aligns the nodes.