# TikZ - "Hand-like" style a flow chart

Tags: tikz-styles

I would like to imitate the following formatting.

[image]

The randomness of the styles should be adjustable by indicating the seed used so that the same diagram is always repeated if necessary.

I would also like to have the same vertical distances between the nodes automatically if possible.

Here is a starting code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows}


\begin{document}

% The styles
\tikzset{
    block/.style = {
        rectangle, draw, 
        text width=5em, text centered, 
        minimum height=4em
    },
    connection/.style={
        draw, 
        -latex'
    }
}

    
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (lint) 
          {Lint};
    \node [block, below of = lint] (run) 
          {Run unit and integration tests};
    \node [block, below of = run] (build) 
          {Build image};
    \node [block, below of = build] (upload) 
          {Upload image to registry};
    \node [block, below of = upload, node distance=2.5cm] (update) 
          {Update running service to use new image};
    % Draw arrows.
    \path [connection] (lint)   -- (run);
    \path [connection] (run)    -- (build);
    \path [connection] (build)  -- (upload);
    \path [connection] (upload) -- (update);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39296/36296 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74878/create-xkcd-style-diagram-in-tex for some starting points

Comment: And `\tikzstyle` is obsolete. Use `\tikzset` instead

Comment: An old code copied and pasted by a lazy person... The code in the question has been updated.  :-)

Comment: Re distance between nodes: Use the `positioning` library and its keys <placement>=of <reference>` instead of `<placement> of=<reference>`. [\[1\]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386), [\[2\]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94396). If you have figured out the randomness and the decorations you will have to do the drawing and the filling separately since they describe different paths: [`preaction`/`postaction`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#sec-15.10).

Comment: That said, the real challenge will be to setup the decorations. sometimes the sides of the rectangle are straight but drawn separately. Sometimes two of them meet in the corner, some are connected with a big arc. Some are straight, some are tilted slightly. Some sides are interrupted. The `calligraphy` library might help with the varying line width.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Do you know how to use `calligraphy` with the accepted answer?

Comment: I haven't tested it but instead of `draw`ing the border, you should be able to use the option `use pen` on it after you've defined a `\pen`, of course and have loaded the `calligraphy` library.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, it's not exactly like your image, but it's a (relatively) easy solution using `random steps` from the `decorations.pathmorphing` library. As a `preaction` the nodes are filled, but with different settings from the way they are drawn. You can adjust those however you like.

The arrows are actually two superimposed arrows (yellow on black) with the second drawn shorter and thinner than the first as a `postaction`.

I used `chains` to fix the distance between nodes. Then `every join` can be set to the `connection` style.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.pathmorphing, chains}

\begin{document}

% The styles
\tikzset{
    block/.style = {join,
        rectangle, draw, line width=2pt, 
        text width=3cm, text centered, 
        minimum height=1.5cm, rounded corners,
        decorate, decoration={random steps, segment length=6mm, amplitude=1pt},
        preaction={fill=#1, rectangle, 
        minimum width=3cm, 
        minimum height=1.5cm, rounded corners,
        decorate, decoration={random steps, segment length=3mm, amplitude=2mm}
        }
    },
    connection/.style={
        shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt,
        -{Stealth[length=2mm, inset=0, width=4mm, round]},
        line width=1.5mm,
        decorate, decoration={random steps, segment length=4pt, amplitude=.1pt},
        postaction={draw, yellow, shorten <=3pt, shorten >=3.5pt, line width=1mm,
            -{Stealth[length=1.1mm, inset=0, width=2.5mm, round]}}
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going below, node distance = 6mm, every join/.style=connection]
\pgfmathsetseed{14159}
    \node [on chain, block=blue!30!green!70!white] (lint) {Lint};
    \node [on chain, block=blue!40!green!70!white] (run) {Run unit and integration tests};
    \node [on chain, block=blue!50!green!70!white] (build) {Build image};
    \node [on chain, block=blue!60!green!70!white] (upload) {Upload image to registry};
    \node [on chain, block=blue!70!green!70!white] (update) {Update running service to use new image};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The output is very good. Thanks for this!

Comment: Is there a way to select the seed for randomness?

Comment: @projetmbc: I think you can use `\pgfmathsetseed`. I edited my response with an example.